# How do I change the value of an attribute?

Tags: javascript

I need to change the value/content of vastAdTagUrl in this code:
It needs to be a function that I can call. I know it sounds easy, and it probably is, but I just can't make it work...

```
<script id="player1">
    var mediaEventNames = 'loadstart progress suspend abort error emptied stalled play pause loadedmetadata loadeddatawaiting playing canplay canplaythrough seeking seeked timeupdate ended ratechange durationchange volumechange'.split(' ');
    $('video').mediaelementplayer({
    pluginPath: '../build/',
    vastAdTagUrl: 'http://ab166247.adbutler-meson.com/vast.spark?setID=1260&ID=166247&pid=17922',

    vastEnableSkip: true,
    vastSkipSeconds: 3,
    features: ['playpause','current','progress','duration','volume','fullscreen','vast'],

    success: function(media, node, player) {
        for (var i=0; i<mediaEventNames.length; i++) {
            (function(eventName) {
                media.addEventListener(eventName, function(e) {
                    console.log('event', eventName);
                });
            })(mediaEventNames[i]);
        }     
    }
}); 
</script>
```

I find it hard because it is not a plain variable and not inside something that can only be reached by an ID. I appreciate all help I can get.

Comment: I don't understand the problem, what's stopping you from just changing the code?

Comment: Are you injecting your Javascript into an 3rd party website? Like a adware plugin or an evil MITM proxy?

Comment: I want to change the value after some time.... Through a function.
After a person has viewed the video I want to change the ad, therefore the contents of VastAdTagUrl.

No 3rd party website/plugin stuff, no, just my own website.

Comment: vastAdTagUrl = $('someinput').val(); so you can dynamicly edit the someinput value without changing the code.

Comment: you need to provide getters/setters. You can see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/14m0vuqq/

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar I totally see how that should work. But I can't get it working. I wonder where in the code I should instantiate the object.

I pasted the first code in your fiddle in a script tag, and tried to instantiate the object like this here, and call the method. The URL of the code is http://folk.uib.no/jvi041/player/tests/utentv2.html

and in the code above i changed to this:

$('video').mediaelementplayer({
    pluginPath: '../build/',
    var obj = new A();
    vastAdTagUrl: obj.getVastAdTagUrl();,

Comment: That is a configuration object for the player plugin, it seems it doesn't have the functionality to modify that value, or even show the add after the first time, probably you should have to modify the source code to do what you want.

Comment: Try checking the methods related to vast.. by doing player.vastSomething and loading the plugin like this , try something like this var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#video', {pluginPath: '../build/',
 //vastAdTagUrl: 'http://ab166247.adbutler-meson.com/vast.spark?setID=1260&ID=166247&pid=17922',
 vastAdTagUrl: '../media/minoto-vast.xml', 
 vastEnableSkip: true,
 vastSkipSeconds: 3,
 features: ['playpause','current','progress','duration','volume','fullscreen','vast'], success: function(mediaElement, originalNode) {
    // do things
}});